# JS function to change page isn't showing nextPage

Tags: javascript, html, function

Newbie here building my 2nd website trying to get to grips with basics.

I have two html documents, and am trying to use JS to navigate between them, this is by far the most advanced thing i have done to date, so I am clueless on what i can even try!

I have checked the basics:

- making sure i have called the correct variables
- checked the class .page is listed on the page/section i am trying to display.

I have been following a youtube video - but my design, content and pages are different so the video hasn't helped on this occasion.

My aim is when I click the second dot (the svg in `.toggle`), for the gallery page to display (the first page disappears fine :D). I have copied the code i think is relevant (I am probably wrong?) so let me know if more is needed.

index.html:
has a main with class of page which disappears fine

gallery.html:

```
<section class="page">
    <div class="gallery">

        <div class="image" id="beeFace"></div>

        <div class="image" id="honeyComb"></div>

        <div class="image" id="pollen"></div>

        <div class="image" id="closeUp"></div>

        <div class="image" id="nectar"></div>

        <div class="image" id="hover"></div>

    </div>
</section>
```

javascript:

```
function wrapperFunction() {
    const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
    const pages = document.querySelectorAll(".page");

    let current = 0; //page tracker

    function nextSlide(pageNumber) {
        const nextPage = pages[pageNumber];
        const currentPage = pages[current];
        const currentLeft = currentPage.querySelector(".beeImage #beeLeft");
        const currentRight = currentPage.querySelector(".beeImage #beeRight");


        const tl = new TimelineMax();

        tl.fromTo(currentLeft, 0.3, {y:"-10%"}, {y:"-100%"})
        .fromTo(currentRight, 0.3, {y:"10%"}, {y:"-100%"},"-=0.2")
        .fromTo(currentPage, 0.3, {opacity:1, pointerEvents:"all"}, {opacity:0, pointerEvents:"none"})
        .fromTo(nextPage, 0.3, {opacity:0, pointerEvents:"none"}, {opacity:1, pointerEvents:"all"})


        current = pageNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any chance you could cut down your code to a [mcve], this is way to much code in comparison to the real problem

Comment: hello, yes done. I think i have figured it out though.. so my html is currently in two different files so i have a const that effectively is an array for .pages? however because i have an event listener for a click, when i click im only on the one html file, so it thinks there is only index 0. I'm going to give this a go again in the morning and consolidate my html to see if it works.